# Is the Nvidia driver automatically installed by Windows 10 the proper one?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

I just reinstalled Windows 10 from stratch on my PC. Previous versions of Windows would usually come preinstalled with a generic video driver, and the first thing I would do after install would be to go the Nvidia website to download and install the latest official driver for my card. This time, I noticed that Windows automatically installed what already appears to be the official Nvidia driver (including all the usual Nvidia apps and menus). Should I trust this to be the correct and latest version of the driver? Or should I still manually download and install the one from the Nvidia website in any case?

Comment: Its not the most recent version.  You should install drivers directly from Nvidia.

Comment: [Should I install graphics card drivers from Windows Update?](http://superuser.com/questions/184319/should-i-install-graphics-card-drivers-from-windows-update)